# Formatting in excel showing -0.02 as -0

Tags: formatting, excel-2007, excel-2010, number-formatting

I have applied following format on excel cell. `##0\%;[Red]\(##0\%\)`

This format is rounding off the value and showing negative number in red color within brackets.

issue: small values such as -0.03 is shown as (0%) instead of coming as 0%. showing 0 as negative does not make any sense.

What should i do to force -0 to be shown as 0 instead of (0).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will color and parenthesise your number based on its actual *value,* not how it displays.

Hence, it you don't want that showing up, you need to change the actual value, such as with:

```
=trunc(<current formula>,0)
```

or (most likely better):

```
=round(<current formula>,0)
```

Alternatively, you can apply conditional formatting to a cell so that the given formatting is only applied if, for example, `round(<this cell>,0) = 0`.

In that case, you could apply `"##0\%"` if the rounding results in 0 or your current format `"##0\%;[Red]\(##0\%\)"` otherwise.